# Retrieving last 24 hours records starting from specific hour

Tags: hadoop, hive

Need to retrieve number of records inserted in last one day between a specific time interval in hive.

Example:

```
select * 
  from table 
 where date1 BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - 1 DAY AND hour(hour1) >= 03) AND (CURRENT_DATE AND hour(hour1) < 03)
```

How can we achieve this.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what source table contains in both date1 and hour1 and desired output

Comment: @leftjoin      date is of the format 2019-04-06T17:56:59.798+11:00, date1 is the TO_DATE value that is 2019-4-06 , hour 1 stores the hour value that is 17 in this case. Need to retrieve all such records which are there in the db from one day before added after 3am till 3 am on today's date.

Comment: was able to solve it, using OR between the date span. Thank you.